# c# LINQ find value in datareader

Tags: c#, linq, datareader

This is my table on MySQL database :

```
+----------+--------+---------+
| UserName | Region | UsercIX |
+----------+--------+---------+
| a123456  | X410   | NULL    |
| a123456  | X420   |       1 |
| a123456  | X430   | NULL    |
| a123456  | X440   |       1 |
+----------+--------+---------+
```

The user **a123456** is write enabled for **X420** and **X440** Region *(UsercIX=1)* and reading for **X410** and **X430** Region (*UsercIX=NULL*).

I need to find in this table -via **LINQ** or your suggestion- only values equals to 1 in the column **UsercIX**, because with **DataReader** extracting the first value of the column which is null.

Please an you help me ?

My code below

```
using (OdbcDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
           int UsercIX = Convert.ToInt32(reader["UsercIX"]);  //IS NULL
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit #01**

```
using (OdbcDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            int UsercIX = reader.GetInt32(6);
        }
    }                            
}
```

Comment: You can catch `InvalidCastException` or test for `DBNull.Value` beforehand (you should test `DBNull` anyway, given the source of the data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May i suggest doing a try parse on the value?

```
     int number;

     bool success = Int32.TryParse((reader["UsercIX"], out number);
     if (success)
     {
             // it worked, yay
     }
     else
     {
             // 
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should access the values in this way:

```
**SqlDataReader** reader = command.ExecuteReader();

int UsercIX = reader.GetInt32(2);
```

with in the while loop.
The colums start with 0

Eventually you run in an error when accesing Null-value then use a try() {} catch() {} structure to avoid this.
 - Hope this helps!

Here is a complete example for mysql;

```
public void CreateMySqlDataReader(string mySelectQuery, MySqlConnection myConnection)
{
MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(mySelectQuery, myConnection);
myConnection.Open();
MMySqlDataReader myReader;
myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
try
{
while(myReader.Read())
{
Console.WriteLine(myReader.GetString(0));
}
}
finally
{
myReader.Close();
myConnection.Close();
}
}
```

Comment: thank you I have error on `int UsercIX = reader.GetInt32(2);` ... Invalid cast specified because the value of first row is null

Comment: You should better use:
 SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

not OdbcDataReader

Comment: Please see **Edit #01** in my first question